# Spring Security 6.0.1 custom AuthenticationProcessingFilter authentication success but won't redirect to index page

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using Spring Boot 3.0.1 with Spring Security 6.0.1 to build a web service.

My problem is I can't login to the server after adding a custom AuthenticationProcessingFilter to `HttpSecurity`.

When debugging the program, I found that the authenticate method was able to return AuthenticationToken in my custom AuthenticationProvider. After the authenticate, it won't redirect to the index page but still go to the login page.

I've tried to remove the custom AuthenticationProcessingFilter, it works fine to login/logout.

My codes:

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true) 
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider myUsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder =
                http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(myUsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider);
        return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(myUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(http), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);// Works fine if comment this line.
        //http.addFilterBefore(myMobilephoneAuthenticationFilter(http), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        

        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests((authorize) ->
                        authorize.requestMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                ).formLogin(
                        form -> form
                                .loginPage("/login")
                                .loginProcessingUrl("/login/submit")
                                .defaultSuccessUrl("/index")
                                .permitAll()
                ).logout(
                        logout -> logout
                                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?msg=logout")
                                .permitAll()
                );
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter myUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter filter = new MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authManager(httpSecurity));
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler("/index"));
        filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler("/login?msg=invalid_simple"));
        filter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/login/submit");
        
        return filter;
    }
}
```

**MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider**

```
@Component
public class MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private MyUserService myUserService;
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {

        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        UserDetails dbUser = myUserService.loadUserByUsername(name);

        if (passwordEncoder().matches(password, dbUser.getPassword())) {
            var authorities = List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
            // use the credentials
            // and authenticate against the third-party system
            return new MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    name, password, authorities);
        } else {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Wrong password");
//            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

**MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter**

```
Same as org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
```